# What would be a proper feature extraction method to discriminate orientation of 3d shaded cylinders?

Tags: image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-extraction

Generally, I'm interested to in a neural network implementation to resolve a shape from shading problem. So far, to start with, I have gotten a simple shape from shading implementation.

Particularly with this question, however, I'm looking to train a regressionj model that would learn a 3d orientation of a cylinder in 3d space given it's shading. Each image is simply a grayscale 3d shaded cylinder. Across the dataset only the size and orientation vary.

The texture is assumed to be mate and the light source always has the same position with each cylinder image.

As I've found a vast body of literature on the problem, I've quickly realised that what I need for the moment should be much simpler. Therefore, I just need an advice: what would be a proper image descriptor suitable for the problem above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got my hands on resolving this problem, below is the way I did it. @jnovacho answer is exactly useful, and when I did it I realized how trivial may it be for computer vision experts. Nevertheless, since I myself saw a need to post the question here originally, I thought I should maybe give a better detailed answer as well.

First, since the question specified the problem poorly, I should denote that I have a set of gray cylinders lit from a single source from above. Cylinders can rotate, vary in size and be displaced. The task is to learn the rotation of the cylinder, invariant to size and position.

0) A sample cylinder to handcraft the solution is this one.
[image]

1) A set of 2D Gabors are used to catch the gradient within the cylinder. In order to find the right Gabor parameters, I varied the bandwidth and the size of the filter by hand until it was visible that the internal gradient is detected as well as the edges are. The figure shows an asymmetrical Gabor on the left, and two convolutions of this exact filter with the original cylinder image. As convolutions are overlayed with the grayscale image, it is seen that different orientations of the filter produce responses at different areas of the cylinder. The strongest responses are on the edges, but there is a weaker response to the internal shading of the cylinder as well. This internal gradient is the feature that I need to extract.
[image]

2) Now in order to get this shading gradient, I get rid of the edges by combining responses from 8 Gabor orientations. Basically, taking the maximum over all eight convolutions at each pixel gives a good estimate of the edges around this cylinder. However, the edges are not exactly what is needed, so from this maximal image, I construct a bitmask to get rid of them and only get the internal gradient. Shortly speaking, I threshold off the weak responses to only get the edge image, apply thickening and closing morphological operations. Then apply logical AND to this thickened edge and the maxed convolution converted to black and white and finally erode it. The result is the mask of the patch approximately the size of the internal gradient of the cylinder. Now I just apply this bitmask to the original to get Gabor responses to the internal shading only, without the edge information. The image shows, left to right, the maximum pull of the filter responses, the bitmask constructed through operatind with image morphology described above, and the resulting internal gradient after applying the bitmask.
[image]

3) Now as soon as the shading gradient is there, it is to get a feature representing the original orientation robust against position and size. It seems to be enough to average all the responses of this internal gradient, still keeping the original Gabor orientation. So, with 8 Gabor orientations the feature vector would be an 8-vector of average responses across all sampling points within the internal gradient region extracted at previous steps. In order not to consider each single pixel value, I downsample the image by taking each 5th or 5th only. In order to see empirically that the gradient is picked correctly, the left image is the vector plot, where each arrow is oriented in the direction the original Gabor was, and it is proportionally as long as strong is the response. So dots across the image and, importantly, the edges, show zero strength responses, while the arrows actually indicate the gradient direction. Now I can potentially take the average for each orientation for non-zero values, so the right picture shows the histograms of all non-zero responses across 8 orientations for this given cylinder, where each blue line are the responses at one sampling pixel. I also give an example of another cylinder image, where there happens to be some noise from the exposed internal part of the cylinder, and the gradient area is generally smaller.[image]

4) Finally, just to obtain this 8-vector feature with some invariance across position and size(and potentially some lighting intensity), I average, for each orientation, the sum of all non-zero responses over all non-zero responses. This feature is illustrated in red within the same histogram as above, which was normalized and taken without negative values, since they are symmetrical. I've thrown in a couple of other cylinder orientations to show a certain degree of invariance. The final 8-vector feature is in red left to it's cylinder.[image]

At last, this can e now given to a regression model that learns orientation. However, one obvious problem is the dismissed concavity gradient, which is indicative of the orientation over the 3rd axis(one pointed from the viewer, as forseen by @jnovacho). Fortunately, it might be treated differently within the scope of a different problem I needed this feature for.

Answer (score 1):

Rotation in Z axis (considering that Z axis is pointing from you to projetcion plane) is simple, it's just the rotation of the bounding box. To solve problem with distortion due to rotation in other axes you can take into account the elliptic plane section on top of the cylinder, the find minor and major axis and calculate the projection.

In two other axes I would choose some gradient approach. Using some gradient operator you should be able to find contours of areas with same shade intesity. Those contours are made of point with same distance from light source and thus creating conic sections (in this case straight line is conic section too).

After extracting the conic sections I would probably run some regression algorithm to find the equatin of the conic section.

Last step would be to calculate the actual transform in space. You would have to take into account the projection plane and projection transormation, but I think it should be possible.

EDIT:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Nahd.png

I have created this simple image of cylinder. Then I decreased the number of color to 16. As you can see individual shades of gray are now visible. I think it should be possible to use edges of the regions to aproximate the rotation of the cylinder.

In my case was used parallel lighting engine, so the edges are actually line segments. But if I would use point lighting engine, the egdes would have different shape - they would be part of ellipse.

Using some 3D-math it could be possible to calculate back aproximation of the cylinder position. I'm not really sure about particular methods, this is just a guess. Also I think it's not possible to find unique inverse transformation for projection transform. That could complicate things.

PS: Do you have any sample data?

Comment: Thank you for a useful comment, @jnovacho, I didn't realize I should do the axes separately. With Z axes it's clear, but for X,Y: can you elaborate on "some gradient approach" and/or point to particular methods? Also if there is a chance to, I am still in hope of not using separate algorithms for extracting Z(as defined in the answer) and X,Y axes. I wonder what would happen if I apply various image descriptors that do compute the gradient orientation, like SIFT or SURF and then feed it to the classifier. I am not exactly familiar with any of them yet, thus this thinking can be too naive.

Comment: resp to EDIT: Actually you're right, with individual shades of gray it may be possible to facilitate thresholded edge detectors. That's a cool idea! What complicates things a bit for me is that I haven't done any computational geometry before, so yesterday I spent the whole day to draw a simple cylinder. On the other hand, I don't need to precisely/analytically compute the original position. I rather need to compute a set of features from cylinder shading that allow to coarsely classify 3d orientation. Building a dataset is another problem, I only have 1 sample yet: http://imm.io/1iyBI